# how to create a cron to execute a script every 1 min magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, script

I have created a script that deletes duplicated option for **custom attribute** because this attribute product will generate duplicated value after every save or edit of the product so how to proceed to execute this xscript automatically every 1 minute and thanks in advance 
Here is my code according to what you have suggest :

class Test
{

private $_objectManager;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
){
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
}


public function execute()
{

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("Cron is working !");
    $logger->info(__METHOD__);

    return $this;

    // You can write your code logic here
    $attributeCode = 'choix_prix_product';
    $attribute = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $products = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $option['value']);

        $productIds = [];
        foreach ($products as $prod) {
            $productIds[] = $prod->getId();
        }


    }
    $duplicateOptions = [];
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        // because the first option can be blank
        if(!empty(trim($option['label']))) {
            $products = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $option['value']);

            if ($products->count()) {
                $productsCount = $products->count();
            } else {
                $productsCount = 0;
            }

            $duplicateOptions[$option['label']][$option['value']] = $productsCount;
        }
    }
    foreach ($duplicateOptions as $key => $value) {
        if (count($value) > 1) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                if ($v == 0) {
                    $duplicateOptions[$key]['delete'][] = $k;
                }
            }

            if (isset($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete'])) {
                /**
                 * if multiple options are in delete array,
                 * i.e. multiple option ids have zero product count
                 */
                if (count($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete']) > 1) {
                    sort($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete']); // sort the array
                    array_shift($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete']); // remove the first item of the array

                    /**
                     * if you assume that the older option id is the duplicate one
                     * then, you keep the older option id in the delete list
                     * and remove the latest/newly-added attribute option from the delete list
                     */
                    // rsort($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete']); // reverse sort the array
                    // array_shift($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete']); // remove the first item of the array
                }

                // DELETE DUPLICATE ATTRIBUTE OPTIONS
                foreach ($duplicateOptions[$key]['delete'] as $optionId) {
                    $optionModel = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option')->load($optionId);
                    try {
                        $optionModel->delete();
                        echo '<font color="green">"'.$key.' ('.$optionId.')" duplicate option deleted!</font><br />';
                        $data .= 'Option Value: ' . $key . ', ' . 'Option ID: ' . $optionId;
                        $data .= "\n";
                    } catch(Exception $e) {
                        echo '<font color="red">'. $e->getMessage() .'</font><br />';
                        $data .= $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: See this link https://crontab.guru/#*/1_*_*_*_* using this you can make cron expression as per your requirement and copy that expression and past into `<schedule></schedule>`

Answer (score 0):

Create custom module and follow step by step.

Step1 :  `app/code/Adamsmage/Cron/etc/crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default"> <!-- Doesn't need to be unique -->
        <job name="cron_example" instance="Adamsmage\Cron\Cron\Example" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Step2 : `app/code/Adamsmage/Cron/Cron/Example.php`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Cron\Cron;
class Example {

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->_logger->info(__METHOD__);

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Cron is working !");
        return $this;
    } }
```

Step3 : run below command to execute cron.

`magento cron:run [--group="cron_group_name"]`

Comment: How to call my script in this class

Comment: add your code in execute function

Comment: i tried this code but i can't see the file /var/log/cron.log and how to know that this code works fine so that the duplicatedoptions are deleted

Comment: please check now, I update my code. which is generate templog.log file when cron execute.

Comment: ok but i tried you code yesterday i did not find any log file and the option duplicated and not deleted after 1 minute